# How do you get ListBoxItem.IsMouseCaptured to trigger style changes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I'm using the following style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Button-Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <TextBlock Padding="10"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Button-Foreground-Disabled}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Button-Background-Hover}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Button-Foreground}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Button-Background-Hover}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Button-Foreground-Hover}"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Button-Foreground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Button-Foreground-Hover}"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The issue I'm having is that the `IsMouseCaptured` trigger never occurs.  It keeps the `IsMouseOver` style even when I clicked it (the background is the same color intentionally, but I've tried changing just to experiment and it doesn't change at all and the foreground certainly doesn't change).

Is there a way to have triggers occur for a specific list box item when it is clicked?  All the other triggers are working as expected.

Comment: Just to share what I have noticed, it seems that `IsMouseCaptured` property never changes in the case of `ListBoxItem` whereas `IsMouseCaptureWithin` property does when it hosts UIElement whose `IsMouseCaptured` propery changes such as `Button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have triggers occur for a specific list box item when it is clicked?

Not using any built-in property.

You could create your own custom `ListBoxItem` that adds an `IsPressed` property that you can bind to:

```
public class CustomListBoxItem  : ListBoxItem
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPressedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(IsPressed), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomListBoxItem), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsPressed
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsPressedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsPressedProperty, value);

    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        IsPressed = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        IsPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Unless you create the `ListBoxItem` elements explicitly, you will also need a custom `ListBox` that generates containers of your custom type:

```
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride() =>
        new CustomListBoxItem();
}
```

Comment: This was the solution, I had to override a few more event handlers to compensate for click and drag, it works in single selection mode, which is what I need, untested in multiple.  I added a OnMouseEnter which sets IsPressed to true if the MouseDevice.LeftButton is pressed and an OnMouseLeave that sets IsPressed to false.